# High CPU usage 20.04

Tags: 20.04, xps, intel-cpu

Need to troubleshot this high CPU performance.

Linux alaa-XPS13-9333 5.8.0-50-generic #56~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 21:46:35

UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your `top` output:

- Turn off stacer
- Turn off your dropbox client
- Close the chrome tabs
- Turn off the music

...and you should find your Mate Desktop CPU usage considerably lessened also.

You can also turn them off one at a time to see the impact of each on your desktop CPU usage.

Comment: Still not normal, these very high CPU values for a quad core processor of a Dell XPS

Comment: @vanadium agreed

Comment: There was no music. If close chrome there will be no browser.